Trying to use ARView session's currentFrame camera transforms to identify wall corners in capturedImage
I am trying to determine the corners of a RoomPlan-detected wall using the information available in the ARView session's frame, but can't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong. The corners appear to be correct relative to each other, but the wall appears too large when I render it. (I'm also not sure I'm handling the image rotation correctly either, which may be compounding my problem) Here is the code I currently have, along with a sample image, and the resulting image when I pass it through the perspective filter. It is close but isn't cropping the walls and floors correctly.
func captureSession(_ session: RoomCaptureSession, didChange room: CapturedRoom) {
    for surface in room.walls {
        if let frame = self.arView.session.currentFrame {
            var image: CGImage? = nil
            VTCreateCGImageFromCVPixelBuffer(frame.capturedImage, options: nil, imageOut: &image)

            let wallTransform = surface.transform
            let cameraTransform = frame.camera.transform
            let intrinsics = frame.camera.intrinsics
            let projectionMatrix = frame.camera.projectionMatrix

            let width = surface.dimensions.y
            let height = surface.dimensions.x

            let inverseCameraTransform = simd_inverse(cameraTransform)

            let wallTopRight = simd_float4(width/2, height/2, 0, 1)
            let wallTopLeft = simd_float4(-width/2, height/2, 0, 1)
            let wallBottomRight = simd_float4(width/2, -height/2, 0, 1)
            let wallBottomLeft = simd_float4(-width/2, -height/2, 0, 1)

            let worldTopRight =  wallTransform * wallTopRight
            let worldTopLeft = wallTransform * wallTopLeft
            let worldBottomRight = wallTransform * wallBottomRight
            let worldBottomLeft = wallTransform * wallBottomLeft

            let cameraTopRight = projectionMatrix * inverseCameraTransform * worldTopRight
            let cameraTopLeft = projectionMatrix * inverseCameraTransform * worldTopLeft
            let cameraBottomRight = projectionMatrix * inverseCameraTransform * worldBottomRight
            let cameraBottomLeft = projectionMatrix * inverseCameraTransform * worldBottomLeft

            let imageTopRight = intrinsics * simd_float3(cameraTopRight.x / cameraTopRight.w, cameraTopRight.y / cameraTopRight.w, cameraTopRight.z / cameraTopRight.w)
            let imageTopLeft = intrinsics * simd_float3(cameraTopLeft.x / cameraTopLeft.w, cameraTopLeft.y / cameraTopLeft.w, cameraTopLeft.z / cameraTopLeft.w)
            let imageBottomRight = intrinsics * simd_float3(cameraBottomRight.x / cameraBottomRight.w, cameraBottomRight.y / cameraBottomRight.w, cameraBottomRight.z / cameraBottomRight.w)
            let imageBottomLeft = intrinsics * simd_float3(cameraBottomLeft.x / cameraBottomLeft.w, cameraBottomLeft.y / cameraBottomLeft.w, cameraBottomLeft.z / cameraBottomLeft.w)

            let topRight = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(imageTopRight.x), y: CGFloat(imageTopRight.y))
            let topLeft = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(imageTopLeft.x), y: CGFloat(imageTopLeft.y))
            let bottomRight = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(imageBottomRight.x), y: CGFloat(imageBottomRight.y))
            let bottomLeft = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(imageBottomLeft.x), y: CGFloat(imageBottomLeft.y))

            if let image {
                let filter = CIFilter.perspectiveCorrection()
                filter.inputImage = CIImage(image: UIImage(cgImage: image))
                filter.topRight = topRight
                filter.topLeft = topLeft
                filter.bottomRight = bottomRight
                filter.bottomLeft = bottomLeft

                let transformedImage = filter.outputImage

                if let transformedImage {
                    let context = CIContext()
                    if let outputImage = context.createCGImage(transformedImage, from: transformedImage.extent) {
                        let wall = Wall(id: surface.identifier, image: outputImage, surface: surface)
                        self.walls.append(wall)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}



